# Hosting WebSocket stream API in ASP.NET Core (PubSub + Rate Limitting)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, websocket

I want to host a WebSocket stream API, mostly for financial data, such as [Deribit JSON RPC API over websocket](https://docs.deribit.com/#json-rpc-over-websocket) and [Binance WebSocket Stream API](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#subscribe-to-a-stream). I don't want to bother with SignalR because there is no SignalR client support for most of the languages.

Requirements:

- The hosted endpoint should be using the WebSocket protocol, i.e. `wss://...`
- Rate limitting capabilities such as [Binance's](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#websocket-limits). Speaking of it, they added Sliding Window Rate Limiting in .NET 7 ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/)). I also found another solution using Redis ([Redis Sliding Window Rate Limiting](https://developer.redis.com/develop/dotnet/aspnetcore/rate-limiting/middleware)).
- If you take a look at the Binance WebSocket Stream API, you'll see that you're able to subscribe/unsubscribe to a stream which makes me think that they are using some kind of a PubSub system over WebSockets.

I did some research and found Azure Web PubSub as a solution ([use case here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-build-realtime-apps-with-websockets-and-azure-web-pubsub-now-in-preview/)) which is using WebSockets and it is intended for non Azure clients (non SignalR clients).

I couldn't find any websocket server frameworks for ASP.NET Core, so here is the question. What do you guys recommend in this case? Not sure if I could achieve the same using RabbitMQ or Kafka.

Comment: There have a WebSockets middleware, you can use it in Asp.net core application. Refer to this article: [WebSockets support in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0). For most applications, we recommend SignalR over raw WebSockets. SignalR provides transport fallback for environments where WebSockets isn't available. It also provides a basic remote procedure call app model. And in most scenarios, SignalR has no significant performance disadvantage compared to using raw WebSockets.

Comment: @ZhiLv, I'm afraid of using that because I was told that "choosing raw websockets is the biggest mistake as it doesn't give memory / scaling / downtime / deployment / resilience / protocol handling / reconnect / metrics / logs / grouping / fanout / security out of box", i.e. the fact that I'm not aware of its disadvantages makes me avoid it. Perhaps if I know its downsides I would've been using it.

Comment: Yeah, so SignalR is a good choice. Refer to [Overview of ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0).